# trying to sum up a column, but some columns contain a character which needs to be there

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with a column that contains `*` next to some of the numbers. That `*` is necessary and needs to stay there. Is there anyway to sum up a column like this:

```
 100*
 100
 50
 10*

 260
```

Comment: How many letters are there in the ""?

Comment: @PaichengWu - sorry i didn't realize that my text got all messed up. There's only ever going to be a * character after the number. As shown in the example.

Comment: @PaichengWu - I'm trying something like this: =SUM(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,"*","") +0) but i keep getting #Value error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Array Formula

If there is only one character following the number, please use the array formula below:

```vb
=SUM(IF(ISTEXT(A1:A4),--LEFT(A1:A4,LEN(A1:A4)-1),A1:A4))
```

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

[image]

## `SUMPRODUCT` function

I modify @Koosh's formula in comment.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,"*",""))
```

Comment: I also was able to figure out something much less complicated in terms of syntax: =SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(0&SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3,"*","")))

Comment: @Koosh Good. I modify your offer to a short version: `=SUMPRODUCT(--SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,"*",""))`.